# Is it possible for stackdriver to recognise syslog input from k8s?

Tags: go, kubernetes, syslog

Unable to get stack driver to recognize syslog levels. Everything appears as an error despite specifying `DEBUG`

```
logwriter, e := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_DEBUG, "myprog")
if e == nil {
    log.SetOutput(logwriter)
}

log.Print("log me")
```

I am aware of format [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages)

if I stdout correct format as json payload stackdriver will magically pick it up and it works for me.

But why can't stackdriver recognize syslog input even if I syslog the json payload?

Answer (score 1):

Syslog is a different protocol.

Try the [golang driver](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/go).

This is tagged with k8s... if you need your kubernetes logs then just use the exporter. If you're just trying to get pod logs, you can send to STDOUT and the [below](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/stackdriver-exporter) will forward for you.